# WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables

Tags: tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I've build a model and tried to compile but ended up with the following warning message.

```
def create_model_xlnet(xlnet_model):
    word_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4096,), name='word_inputs', dtype='int32')

    xlnet = TFXLNetModel.from_pretrained(xlnet_model)
    xlnet.classifier = None
    xlnet_encodings = xlnet(word_inputs)[0]
    
    # Collect last step from last hidden state (CLS)
    doc_encoding = tf.squeeze(xlnet_encodings[:, -1:, :], axis=1)
    
    doc_encoding = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.1)(doc_encoding)
     
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='outputs')(doc_encoding)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[word_inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['tfxl_net_model/transformer/mask_emb:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer_.*0/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*0/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*1/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*1/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*2/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*2/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*3/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*3/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*4/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*4/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*5/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*5/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*6/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*6/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*7/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*7/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*8/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*8/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*9/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*9/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*10/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*10/rel_attn/seg_embed:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*.*11/rel_attn/r_s_bias:0', 'tfxl_net_model/transformer/layer*._11/rel_attn/seg_embed:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?

Comment: This message means that the pretrained model is not trainable.idnyoundont want to fine tune the pretrained model on your task then you can ignore this message. If you want to fine tune then you should set the pretrained layers to be able to be trained.

Comment: Help me understand.. Say I do not want to touch the pre-trained layers, but I add classification layers on top.. Would that still be valid in terms of fine tuning the model to a specific task!

Comment: Yeah, of course. But generally fine tuning is the process of retraining an already trained model in order to apply transfer learning or get the best results out of it. You can use a pretrained model as a feature extractor upon some task specific layers without fine tuning it. But have in mind that you should remove the classification layers of the pretrained model and add yours.